# Add css class to closest tr tag

Tags: jquery, html, razor

I have table in which I want to add a css class to some `tr`. I have this code

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Length; i++)
{
  <tr>
   @if (!Model.Items[i].IsActive)
   {
    <script>
     $(function () {
      $(this).closest("tr").addClass("inActiveTr");
     });
    </script>
   }
<td> ... </td>
...
</tr>
}
```

but it isn't doing anything. What's wrong?

If I just write

```
$("tr").addClass("inActiveTr");
```

inside the function it gives that class to all the `tr` in page

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y6swsfph/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it in your razor server side like this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Length; i++)
{
  <tr@Html.Raw(!Model.Items[i].IsActive ? " class=\"inActiveTr\"" : string.Empty)>
    <td> ... </td>
    ...
  </tr>
}
```

If for some reason you really want to use jQuery to add the class, then you need some sort of identifier for the row so you can target it:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Length; i++)
{
    <tr id="row@(i)">
        <td> ... </td>
        ...
    </tr>

    @if (!Model.Items[i].IsActive)
    {
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#row@(i)').addClass("inActiveTr");
            });
        </script>
    }
}
```